# How to use input text field in table using looping and get specific value for the row selection in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text

I made a table with one of the column contain text field related to its row, please help me to get value from those inputs,
I have API and I fetch it and create table using loop, table is properly show all data, there are 4 columns the last column I want to add text field. whenever I submit this table it must show the value what I put in a respective text field. Suppose I have 10 rows then there is 10 text fields in last column.

Comment: Please add more description and add code for whatever you have done till now. This tells us nothing about your problem.

Comment: @Amruta I am stuck to manage onChange event

Comment: You may need to reach for useRef and split the text fields away into their own components so you can handle state of onChange with more ease.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.